# How to go about splitting up multiple select in a Django form?

Tags: python, django, django-forms

To make a more user-friendly interface on my website I would like to cut up a multiple select in a couple of multiple selects based on an attribute. How would you go about this?

**Models.py**

I basically have 4 classes as visualized below. I have a schedule to which tasks can be related. Furthermore the user needs to be able to assign user fields per schedule. An example of a user field could be 'topic' or 'priority: whatever the user decides. Each user field can have multiple user field values. For example, values for 'priority' could be 'Urgent', 'Normal' and 'No rush'. Each task should then have a value assigned to it. Ideally I would like it only to have one possible value per user field. So following the examples above a task can not be 'urgent' and 'normal' at the same time. This is another thing I need to figure out, so any hints are welcome, but outside the scope of this question.

```py
class Schedule(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

class Tasks(models.Model):
    schedule = models.ForeignKey(Schedule, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.TextField()
    start = models.DateTimeField()
    end = models.DateTimeField()
    userfieldvalues = models.ManyToManyField("UserFieldValues", blank=True)
    def __str__(self):
         return self.title

class UserField(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    schedule = models.ForeignKey(Schedule, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class UserFieldValues(models.Model):
    value = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    userfield = models.ForeignKey(UserField, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="values")
    def __str__(self):
        return self.value
```

[image: Overview of my model classes and relations.]

**Template and forms.py**

I created a form:

```py
class TaskForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Task
        fields = ("title", "start", "end", "userfieldvalues")
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['title'].label = 'Task Title'
        self.fields['title'].widget.attrs['rows'] = 1
        self.fields['start'].widget.format = '%H:%Mh, %d-%m-%Y'
        self.fields['start'].input_formats = ['%H:%Mh, %d-%m-%Y']
        self.fields['end'].widget.format = '%H:%Mh, %d-%m-%Y'
        self.fields['end'].input_formats = ['%H:%Mh, %d-%m-%Y']
```

In my template I render the form. For the user field values it now shows all the options is a multiple select. I would like to create a multiple select per UserField, but I don't know how to go about.

Comment: What do your models look like ?

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers I added the models code.